# Efficient way of converting pandas DataFrame to matrices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have pandas DataFrames that have one "x" column and one "y" column which represent points in a surface, and then many columns with properties of these points. From this I need to create matrices to plot this data. This is a MWE of what I am currently doing:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
        'y': [4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6],
        'z': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    }
)

x_values = sorted(set(df['x']))
y_values = sorted(set(df['y']))
xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(x_values, y_values)
zz = numpy.zeros(xx.shape)
zz[:] = float('NaN')
for nx,x in enumerate(x_values):
    for ny,y in enumerate(y_values):
        zz[ny,nx] = float(df.loc[(df['x']==x) & (df['y']==y), 'z'])

plt.pcolormesh(xx,yy,zz)
plt.show()
```

which works but it is very slow (when the `df` has order 1 million rows). Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `pivot_table` will do the job:

```
zz = df.pivot_table('z', 'y', 'x').to_numpy()

print(zz)
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```